# DeconRNASeq: Extract gene names from returned mixing proportions

Tags: r, rna-seq, bioconductor

*This question was also asked on [Biostars](https://www.biostars.org/p/9526743/)*

I am using the Bioconductor package "DeconRNASeq" to perform tissue deconvolution. Let's say I run the following code (this is from the manual):

```
BiocManager::install(c("DeconRNASeq"))
library(DeconRNASeq)

data(multi_tissue)
datasets <- x.data[,2:11]
signatures <- x.signature.filtered.optimal[,2:6]
proportions <- fraction

res <- DeconRNASeq(datasets, signatures, proportions, checksig=FALSE, known.prop = TRUE, use.scale = TRUE, fig = TRUE). 
res.out <- as.data.frame(res[["out.all"]])
str(res.out)
```

And receive the following results:

```
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ brain : num  0.0468 0.0718 0.0685 0.0424 0.6471 ...
 $ muscle: num  0 0.1172 0.6081 0.0489 0.1344 ...
 $ lung  : num  0.0939 0.0829 0.1265 0.6147 0.0709 ...
 $ liver : num  0.0947 0.6187 0.1355 0.1897 0.0812 ...
 $ heart : num  0.7645 0.1093 0.0615 0.1043 0.0665 ...
```

Is it possible for me to obtain the subset of genes that were successfully deconvolved? For instance, the first sample had 0.0468 proportion from "brain". Is it possible for me to see which genes specifically were composing this 0.0468 proportion?

Note: This R package does not appear to have a Q&A forum. If there is a recommended place to post this question other than Bioinformatics StackExchange, I would be grateful to hear suggestions.

Thank you.